# linux non-standard serial console

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-driver, linux-device-driver

I am porting linux to one of the custom architectures. My serial console is unconventional, in the sense it does not work on interrupts.

I am trying to output messages from linux boot process onto kernel console. I used  register_console and printk started working. Now I can see kernel printk messages being printed on console.

Now I am trying to get messages from the user space process onto console.  I was under the impression that console registered for kernel will also work for user processes. However, it is not working. I am under the impression that I need to install a tty driver for user processes prints.

I am trying to understand how serial consoles are configured for user space and kernel space separately. Can someone please point me to some documentation or explain it.

Thanks

Comment: may be guys from openwrt/ddwrt can help you

Comment: I think the part I am missing here is tty driver which I need to attach to my console.

Comment: "unconventional" but is the serial hardware 8250/16440 UART compliant? From which manufacturer? You should create your own tty driver for your device if it is "unconventional". From experience the uartlite driver is the easiest to modify. Also, FWIW the initial bootconsole is disabled by Linux before initializing the actual console/tty driver to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The console is `/dev/console`, which is one of the few `/dev` files that *really* should exist.