# relation between user space printing, console and tty

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-driver, linux-device-driver

I have already posted a question to do printing from user space on a kind of unconventional serial port. [linux non-standard serial console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270805/linux-non-standard-serial-console)

However, I realized that I am a bit confused over the architecture of user space printing.

1. Where does user space printf send its data?I see stdout/stdin are symbolically linked to one of the tty/pty? But who sets up this link?
2. How does a tty connect to available consoles? Or let us say: how tty core interfaces with console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf()` writes to `stdout`, which is a `FILE *` that wraps file descriptor 1. File descriptors are either inherited from parent or opened explicitely. If you follow the process hierarchy upwards in a typical system you'll finally arrive at a `login` process, which is usually spawned by a `*getty` process. A getty process connects to a terminal with the appropriate settings (line speed, parity, ... on serial lines), and usually spawns `login` on first key / ENTER key. gettys are usually launched directly from `/etc/inittab` on traditional init systems.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` uses inside itself system call write() and writes to file descriptor 1, which is associated with tty device file.

The link you say about is being set by kernel.

Comment: Rite. However, I wanna find out which tty it is? How does kernel decide which tty to use? Is it a configurable option. Can I find out before I compile the kernel.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know kernel internals good enough to answer your question. Look through special kernel literature